# Controlar botones mat-paginator

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estoy montando una tabla, con paginación. Y tengo el problema de que, como la **api** esta **paginada**, al navegar por los botones del `mat-paginator` cuando llega al final de los elementos que tiene el `data-source` de la tabla me deshabilita los botones y no puedo continuar.

Os detallo sobre código.

Recibo el siguiente modelo de la API

```
{
  "content": [{},{}
  ],
  "pageable": {
    "sort": {
      "sorted": false,
      "unsorted": true,
      "empty": true
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
  },
  "totalPages": 3,
  "totalElements": 119,
  "last": false,
  "size": 50,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": {
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true,
    "empty": true
  },
  "numberOfElements": 50,
  "first": true,
  "empty": false
}
```

Como véis, el modelo me dice que tengo 119 elementos totales, pero que solo se me van a devolver 50. Por lo tanto, estos 50 (que vienen contenidos en el `content`) son los que bindeo al `data-source`

He estado mirando la documentación de Angular Material y veo que si que tiene métodos para poder saber si el botón está deshabilitado, pero no para habilitarlo.

Para que quede claro, los botones a los que hago referencia, son los siguientes

[image: Botonera Tabla Angular Material]

¿Alguna idea de como solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

supongo que usaste la paginación normal de Angular Material, por eso solo te muestra los primeros 50 registros.

En la documentación de Angular Material:
[Angular Material Tablas](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

En los ejemplos viene uno en específico que te puede ayudar en tu caso:
[image: Muestra la tabla y la paginacion de una API paginada]

De igual forma esta el enlace a Stackblitz con un [Ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/table-http-example.ts)